# ASP.NET Core 2.0 unauthorized redirect using path only

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an application which is accessed via HTTPS, but is "reverse proxied" to the server using plain HTTP. It is set up on AWS as follows:

`[BROWSER] --(https)--> [ELB] --(http)--> [SERVER]`

Everything works fine except when a page is being accessed by an unauthenticated user, the server responds with a HTTP 302 redirect using the whole `protocol://server/path` string. Like so:

`Location: http://my.server.com/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F`

The problem is, it specifies HTTP as the protocol (presumably because it is being connected to by the ELB using HTTP. So the browser redirects the request using HTTP and now an error occurs. Is there a way to customize the redirect such that it redirects using just the path, so irregardless of protocol or hostname, it is redirected properly? Like so:

`Location: /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F`

If this is not advisable, what can be done?

*(note: I've checked other solutions posted on SO. All I've seen so far involve customizing the Path, not removing the protocol://hostname)*

Comment: What authentication do you use?

Comment: Look up the forwarded headers middleware, it's used to read the x-forwarded-proto header and update your request scheme accordingly. Then any links or redirects generated will be correct. It can also do x-forwarded-host if needed. Headers like these should be provided by your reverse proxy.

Comment: Note an old spec required the redirect location to be absolute, not this is no longer the case. For now it's a matter of compatibility.

Comment: @zaitsman I'musing cookie authentication

Comment: @Tratcher Thanks for the suggestion. But what if I'm no longer accommodating older browsers? How do I make the redirect location to be relative?

Comment: I don't recommend it, the whole system will work better if you get the scheme set right.  If you really want to then you can override the redirect event on the cookie options.